# ejs for loop provide only the first element in href link

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a for loop in my home.ejs file as shown below.When i access req.params.name from my app.js file and send it to watch_movie.ejs, only the first index element is send always.Why i can't access other indexes.

home.ejs file:

```
<%data.forEach((item)=>{%>
     <li>
        <a href="watch_movie/:<%=item.Name%>"><img src="<%=item.Image_path%>" height=200px width=150px alt="<%=item.Name%>"></a>                  
        <p><%=item.Name%></p>
    </li>
<%});%>
```

watch_movie.ejs file:

```
<video width="780px" height="450px" controls>
   <source src="<%=path.Video_path%>"><!-getting video_path of only first elemnt ->
        your website doesn't support video
</video>
```

app.js file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   const sql = 'select * from Movies';
   db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
       if (err)
           throw err;
       else {
           const s_res = JSON.stringify(result);
           const j_res = JSON.parse(s_res);
           // const image_data = j_res[0].name;
           res.render('home.ejs', { data: j_res });
       }
   });
});



app.get('/watch_movie/:name', (req, res) => {
   const name = req.params.name;
   const sql = "select * from Movies where Name=name";
   db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
       if (err)
           throw err;
       else {
           const s_res = JSON.stringify(result);
           const j_res = JSON.parse(s_res);
           const movie = j_res[0];
           console.log(movie);//it consoles proper element
           res.render('watch_movie', { path: movie });
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your SQL, note that you wrote: `Name = name`.
Now since SQL is case insensitive, it's basically equivalent to `name = name`, so you comparing the value of name to it's self, which always be `TRUE`.
After that you take the first value from results: `const movie = j_res[0];` so that's why you always get the first row.

The simple solution (not recommended) is to change
 this:

`const sql = "select * from Movies where Name=name";`

To this:

`const sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name="+name;`

That should work, but concatenating the values directly - has [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability, which is a big risk.

So what I recommend you to do, is to use [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with parameterized values.

Like this:

```
const name = req.params.name;
const sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name = ?";
const paramValues = [name];
db.query(sql, paramValues, (err, result) => {
   //Your code...
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked, i should have used prepared statement.